# localhost/phpmyadmin is not working when i am trying to open using admin button in xampp dashboard but working in some other way

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I clicked on admin button in xampp dashboard I am not able to open phpmyadmin console.

After installing xampp, I have changed port of apache server and mysql as well.

but when i am trying to open phpmyadmin console using this link http://localhost:8085/phpmyadmin/ it is allowing me to open that I don't know why it is happening

[image]

As you can see here it is working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to you because you are not specifying the port in the first image.
In the second image it lets you access because you specify the port.

You have to specify the port always with XAMPP.

Try going to the xamp folder> phpmyadmin and edit the file **config.inc.php** as follows : 
Find this : [image] and change the main port to yours. Reload the service and try to connect.

Comment: Just add the port every time you want to access phpmyadmin.
It is a common problem with XAMPP

Comment: but it is supposed to work without specifying port. Isn't it ?

Comment: It's supposed to, i'm updating the answer.